# superset sqlalchemy error:no module named "pymssql"

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql, apache-superset, hdp

I am getting the following error when i try to connect my hdp(ambari) superset with sql server through sqlalchemy

[The error i am getting after clicking "Test connection"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0kE7.png)

I am unable to find the solution to get rid from this error and make my connection successful.

my sqlalchemy url is correct as i retreived the tables from sql server by using same sqlalchemy url in spyder

Any positive help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you have to import pymssql, but its discontinued, and doesnt work for python 3.8. Please read here: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668

Comment: @patchie i have python 3.6 .. ok let me read this article thnks

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pyodbc` instead of `pymssql` module